# How to read specific data from txt file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Help me, I have an data.txt file. and i want to read the specific data in that file `112652447744` that is freespace data in directory C. 
This is the content of my data.txt file:

```
  Caption  FreeSpace     Size          
   C:      112652447744  146776518656  
   D:      295803727872  299962986496  
   E:                                   
   Z:
```

Comment: Would reading all the data from the file and extracting only the data you need from the read list be a possible solution?

Comment: Is there anything you already tried? And do you want it to be dynamic or always the second column in the second row?

Comment: @xZise always the second coloum in the second row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read each line (ignoring the first) and separate it by spaces to get each column. This way you could extract the size and free space for each partition:

```
contents = # here go the file contents
# split the text file into lines and ignore the first line
lines = contents.splitlines()[1:]
part_data = {}
for line in lines:
    columns = line.split()  # split the lines along the white space characters
    if len(columns) != 3:
        continue  # incomplete lines
    part_data[columns[0]] = (columns[1], columns[2])
```

That will give you the free space and size for every partition in the dictionary. To get your actual result it'd be:

```
part_data['C:'][0]
```

If you only want the second column and second row, ignoring the drive letter, you can reduce it to the following:

```
contents = # here go the file contents
second_line = contents.splitlines()[1]
second_column = second_line.split()[1]
```

There you go, but that requires that it always formatted the same. If the second line does not have three columns, it won't actually work and cause an `IndexError` most likely.

Note that `a_string.split()` removes all whitespace automatically, while `a_string.split(' ')` will also return the whitespace in it.

Comment: how to read file.txt.
`file = open('D:\Disk_2016-10-13.txt','r')
contents = file.readlines()
print contensts`
when I run i get this `['\xff\xfeC\x00a\x00p\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00 \x00 \x00F\x00r\x00e\x00e\x00S\x00p\x00a\x00c\x00e\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00S\x00i\x00z\]`

Comment: You first need to decode the contents. The text seems to be encoded as UTF-16, so it is helpful to first decode it: `contents = file.read()` and then `contents = contents.decode("UTF16")`. You don't need to use `readlines()` as `splitlines()` will do the same. And using `splitlines()` will split it after you decoded it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#Open file in lines
file = open('path/to/txt','r').readlines()
#For each line
for disk in file:
    fields = disk.split("\t")
    #To check the total fields...
    if(len(fields)>1):

        print fields[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't say so, but can I assume that you want to "lookup" the value that represents FreeSpace in the row where the Caption is C:?

Unless you need the data in the file for something else, just read in the file line by line until you get your result. The first line will be your headers row, and you use the position of the 'caption_header' and 'fs_header' to parse each subsequent data row.

In your example, this will mean we want to test if the first value of each row contains C:, and if so the answer we're looking for will be in the second column. If we find the answer then there is no need to search the rest of the rows.

```
def find_value(caption_header, fs_header, caption_value, fp):
    fs = None
    with open(fp) as fid:
        headers = fid.readline().strip().split()
        for i, h in enumerate(headers):
            if h == caption_header:
                caption_position = i
            if h == fs_header:
                fs_position = i
        line = fid.readline()
        while line != '':
            values = line.strip().split()
            if values[caption_position] == caption_value:
                fs = values[fs_position]
                break
    return fs
```

Then use it like this:

```
fs = find_value('Caption', 'FreeSpace', 'C:')
```